# QGIS : Problem in importing geopackage that was created from a .dwg file

Tags: qgis, geopackage, dxf, autocad, dwg

I have an AutoCAD .dwg file of stream/channels and hydraulic engineering data. I want to use it in QGIS (3.22.14-Białowieża) for some geoprocessing tasks. The steps I want to take are: Convert the *.dwg file to a geopackage, then extract the specific layers I want from the geopackage to a shapefile.

I used the "import layers from DWG/DFX" option of QGIS to export and view the *.dwg file's contents as a geopackage. After converting, QGIS adds the geopackage to my layers section, and I can visualize easily. However, the problem comes when I close the current project and want to use the exported geopackage in a new QGIS project.

In the new project, I used the Open Data Source Manager option to import the *.gpkg file however, the format of the file contents changes and it is giving me some weird visualization.

Technically I can open a new project and convert the DWG file again. But this takes a lot of time as my DWG file has a lot of objects. Hence, I want to save it as a geopackage so I can quickly open the *.gpkg file whenever I have to work on a new QGIS project.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are details of steps taken by me:

1. Go to project > import/export > import layers from DWG/DFX
2. Target package is the location of my geopackage. This file is named Wurzburg_1.gpkg
3. Source is the AutoCAD file HWSK Würzburg - Los 1 UTM.dwg
4. I give the group name as wurz_1
5. I select all three options: merge layers, expand block references, use curves. Then when all the layers are added, I click ok and the layers of geopackage are added to my project. (Screenshot 1)
6. Now I close this project and open a new project.
7. I go to the Open Data Source Manager and try to open the previously saved geopackage Wurzburg_1.gpkg. But this time, the added layers look totally different that the previous project. Please see screenshot (2 and 3).

[image: Screenshot 1: Output after steps 1 to 5. This is the desired visualization of my data]

[image: Screenshot 2: Opening a new project and adding the geopackage Wurzburg_1.gpkg as in step 7. Please note that the layer names are completely different from the previous image]

[image: Screenshot 3: The view I get when I add the saved geopackage to a new QGIS project. As you can see, this is very different from the view in screenshot 1]

Screenshot 1: output after steps 1 to 5. This is the desired visualization of my data

Screenshot 2: opening a new project and adding the geopackage Wurzburg_1.gpkg as in step 7. Please note that the layer names are completely different from the previous image

Screenshot 3: The view I get when I add the saved geopackage to a new QGIS project. As you can see, this is very different from the view in screenshot 1

Comment: You only saved the data, not the styles. By reloading the data into a new project, you get the default styles for the objects.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I noticed. That is why when I open the saved data in a new project, it does not show the styles but just the geometries. And this is exactly what I am trying to figure out, that how can I save the data along with the styles.

Comment: Karan Mahajan, you can save style as *.qml file (Layer -> Properties -> Style -> Save style), than load style in new project from this file. Or you can save layer definition as *.qlr file and load layer with style.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. Your suggestion worked, and I was finally able to solve my problem. I saved the geopackage as a layer definition file and now I can open it in any project I want without converting the dwg file everytime.

Comment: Karan Mahajan, you can also store your QGIS project in the GeoPackage.